# menu button active when clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I want to make my buttons in the menu bar active, when they are clicked. That also works fine on: portfolio, about, contact.

But the small script is not working on index and services. I have set a body tag on each site.

Does anybody have a clue what could be wrong here? It is the exact same code.

**services.php**

```
<?php include 'resources/includes/header.php' ?>

<body id="services">

<?php include 'resources/includes/navbar.php' ?>

<!-- start intro section -->
<section class="intro">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

            <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="intro-content">
                    <h1>My services are <strong>focused </strong>primarily </h1>
                    <h2>in design, coding and marketing automation </h2>


                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**navbar.php:**

```
<!-- begin header section -->
<header class="header">

    <!-- begin nav -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">

                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span>Tap me!</span>
                        </button>
                        <!-- begin logo in navigation -->
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.php">
                                <img src="images/graphic/webdesign.png">
                        </a>
                        <!-- end logo in navigation -->
                    </div>  

                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                        <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-main pull-right">

                            <!-- begin navigation items -->
                            <li>
                                <a href="index.php">Index</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="services.php">Services</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="portfolio.php">Portfolio</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="aboutme.php">About Me</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="contact.php">Contact</a>
                            </li>
                            <!-- end navigation items -->
                        </ul>   
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- end nav -->

</header
```

**Javascript**
    $(function() {

```
    //highlight the current nav
    $("#index a:contains('Index')").parent().addClass('active');
    $("#services a:contains('Services')").parent().addClass('active');
    $("#portfolio a:contains('Portfolio')").parent().addClass('active');
    $("#about a:contains('About Me')").parent().addClass('active');
    $("#contact a:contains('Contact')").parent().addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Not an answer (as Roberts already provided it) however I'd recommend you implement this in your PHP script by checking what the current request URL is and applying the active class. This way its not dependant on updating your script for each time you add a new page and its instant - not waiting for the script to load and execute.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. When I switch between the pages, there is coming a white blank page. Is that because I have the menu active option like this, or could it be something else. I have included my header, navbar and footer in seperated php documents.

Comment: PHP gets executed by the server side so it builds up the document before sending to the browser (this is good because you have everything your page needs when it loads). Your issue is because your javascript is executing after the page has fully loaded which since your background is controlled in js it causes something called flash of unstyled content. To reduce this you can use a build step that merges all of your JS and CSS into a minified file and also provide some base CSS to make the transition less visible - eg setting a body background colour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the navbar.js script on those two pages.  It's included below main.js on the ones that are working.

```
<!-- Custom Javascript -->
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
<script src="js/navbar.js"></script> // <-- missing from index and services
```

Comment: I might also recommend that a templating system like Twig can really help out in situations like this where you have common things shared across views.